# When does it make sense to give write permission, but not read permission?

Tags: permissions

In UNIX, a file's read and write permissions are independent, so you can make a file writable, but not readable. If I trust someone to write to a file, why wouldn't I want them to be able to read it? If there's important stuff in there, but I don't want him to read it, then why would I give him the ability to overwrite it?

Comment: An upload-only folder.  Perhaps a person implementing a folder that permits students to upload their homework.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can have multple processes to write to a file but you don't want them to see what each other is writing to.

In another word, let's say you have a bank system. Each time a business makes a trasaction, you allow them to write it to a file. But you don't want the business to read what other businesses wrote.

Does this make sense?